# How and when does hyphenation in beamer slides work?

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment, hyphenation

I don't understand how `beamer` handles hyphenation. Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Without hyphenation}
Latex is the stable dispersion (emulsion) of polymer microparticles in an aqueous medium. Latexes may be natural or synthetic. Latex as found in nature is a milky fluid found in 10\% of all flowering plants (angiosperms). It is a complex emulsion consisting of proteins, alkaloids, starches, sugars, oils, tannins, resins, and gums that coagulates on exposure to air. It is usually exuded after tissue injury. In most plants, latex is white, but some have yellow, orange, or scarlet latex. Since the 17th century, latex has been used as a term for the fluid substance in plants. It serves mainly as defense against herbivorous insects.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{With hyphenation}
\begin{overprint}
\onslide<1>
Latex is the stable dispersion (emulsion) of polymer microparticles in an aqueous medium. Latexes may be natural or synthetic. Latex as found in nature is a milky fluid found in 10\% of all flowering plants (angiosperms). It is a complex emulsion consisting of proteins, alkaloids, starches, sugars, oils, tannins, resins, and gums that coagulates on exposure to air. It is usually exuded after tissue injury. In most plants, latex is white, but some have yellow, orange, or scarlet latex. Since the 17th century, latex has been used as a term for the fluid substance in plants. It serves mainly as defense against herbivorous insects.
\end{overprint}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

On the first slide, text will not be hyphenated, whereas it will be on the second. How can I make hyphenation happen on slides without `overprint` blocks?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your post was migrated here from another stackexchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 7):

The text on the first slide seems to use `\raggedright` (or `beamer`s equivalent thereof) which inhibits hyphenation. The text on the second slide uses `\onslide` which internally uses a `minipage` which in turn will cause the text to be typeset justified which in turn allows hyphenation. ;-)

If you want ragged right text plus hypenation for both slides, add the following to your preamble:

```
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\RaggedRight

\makeatletter
\def\@minipagerestore{\RaggedRight}
\makeatother
```

If, on the other hand, you want justified text for both slides, the following preamble code does the trick:

```
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\justifying
```

Answer (score 4):

This doesn't look like intended behaviour from the `beamer` class, but it is caused by different values of `\rightskip`.  Placing `\showthe\rightskip` on the first slide or before the `\onslide` command in the second file shows (in the log file) that the value is

```
> 0.0pt plus 1.0fil.
```

which discourages hyphenation in favour of a ragged right text.  On the other hand on the second slide after `\onslide<1>` the value of `\rightskip` is

```
> 0.0pt.
```

so the text is now set justified to the (left and) right margins, and hyphenation gets used.

To get justified text in the first frame with hyphenation, you need to set `\rightskip` before the frame starts.  You can put `\setlength{\rightskip}{0pt}` in your preamble to affect all frames.  If you just want the first frame to be like this then you can enclosed the setting in a group containing the frame, as in the following example, where we see hyphenation in effect for the first frame, ragged right at the beginning of the second frame and then hyphenation after the `\onframe`.  The third slide shows the opposite effect, by addding the fill back into the `\rightskip` to regain ragged right after the `\onslide`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\bgroup
\setlength{\rightskip}{0pt}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{With hyphenation} 

  Latex is the stable dispersion (emulsion) of polymer microparticles
  in an aqueous medium. Latexes may be natural or synthetic. Latex as
  found in nature is a milky fluid found in 10\% of all flowering
  plants (angiosperms). It is a complex emulsion consisting of
  proteins, alkaloids, starches, sugars, oils, tannins, resins, and
  gums that coagulates on exposure to air. It is usually exuded after
  tissue injury. In most plants, latex is white, but some have yellow,
  orange, or scarlet latex. Since the 17th century, latex has been
  used as a term for the fluid substance in plants. It serves mainly
  as defense against herbivorous insects.
\end{frame}
\egroup

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{With and without hyphenation}
\begin{overprint}
  Latex is the stable dispersion (emulsion) of polymer
  microparticles in an aqueous medium. Latexes may be natural or
  synthetic. Latex as found in nature is a milky fluid found in 10\%
  of all flowering plants (angiosperms). It is a complex emulsion
  consisting of proteins, alkaloids, starches, sugars, oils, tannins,
  resins, and gums that coagulates on exposure to air. It is usually
  exuded after tissue injury.
  \onslide<1> Latex is the stable dispersion (emulsion) of polymer
  microparticles in an aqueous medium. Latexes may be natural or
  synthetic. Latex as found in nature is a milky fluid found in 10\%
  of all flowering plants (angiosperms). It is a complex emulsion
  consisting of proteins, alkaloids, starches, sugars, oils, tannins,
  resins, and gums that coagulates on exposure to air. It is usually
  exuded after tissue injury. In most plants, latex is white, but some
  have yellow, orange, or scarlet latex. Since the 17th century, latex
  has been used as a term for the fluid substance in plants. It serves
  mainly as defense against herbivorous insects.
\end{overprint}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Without hyphenation}
\begin{overprint}
Latex is the stable dispersion (emulsion) of polymer
  microparticles in an aqueous medium. Latexes may be natural or
  synthetic. Latex as found in nature is a milky fluid found in 10\%
  of all flowering plants (angiosperms). It is a complex emulsion
  consisting of proteins, alkaloids, starches, sugars, oils, tannins,
  resins, and gums that coagulates on exposure to air. It is usually
  exuded after tissue injury.
  \onslide<1> \setlength{\rightskip}{0pt plus 1fil}Latex is the stable
  dispersion (emulsion) of polymer 
  microparticles in an aqueous medium. Latexes may be natural or
  synthetic. Latex as found in nature is a milky fluid found in 10\%
  of all flowering plants (angiosperms). It is a complex emulsion
  consisting of proteins, alkaloids, starches, sugars, oils, tannins,
  resins, and gums that coagulates on exposure to air. It is usually
  exuded after tissue injury. In most plants, latex is white, but some
  have yellow, orange, or scarlet latex. Since the 17th century, latex
  has been used as a term for the fluid substance in plants. It serves
  mainly as defense against herbivorous insects.
\end{overprint}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: Frame 1]
[image: Frames 2 and 3]

Comment: +1 for the explanation, but I believe that the lack of hyphenation *is* the intended behavior.

Comment: @egreg Thanks.  What I meant as unintened behaviour is the change of margin caused by the `\onslide` command.